# Copying a histogram from screen device to png in R

Tags: r, png, histogram

I have used the following code to copy a histogram I created to a png file in my working directory:

```
    ## STEP 5: Drawing a histogram, using the Global_active_power variable
hist(tidyFile$Global_active_power, main = "Global Active Power", xlab = "Global Active Power (kilowatts)", ylab = "Frequency", col = "red")
par(mar= c(4, 4, 2, 1))

## STEP 6: Copy to png file
dev.copy(png, filename = "plot1.png", width = 480, height = 480, units = "px", bg = "white")
```

What is returned by R is the following:

```
quartz_off_screen 
            6
```

When I check my working directory folder, the new png file was not created/copied. Only my plot1.R file is found, but no .png file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try putting your `par` command before `hist`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
png("plot1.png", width = 480, height = 480, units = "px", bg = "white")
par(mar= c(4, 4, 2, 1))
hist(tidyFile$Global_active_power, main = "Global Active Power", xlab = "Global Active Power (kilowatts)", ylab = "Frequency", col = "red")
dev.off()
```

your figure should be there now.